# How to snap WPF window to screen edges

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I wrote this code but only the top and left of my multi monitor setup is snapping. The bottom and right edges of the screen is ignored as well as the middle edge between the monitors. How can I snap to those edges?

```
using System;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Interop;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace MyTimer
{
    public partial class MainWindow
    {
        Point LastLeftClickPosition = new Point ( );
        int SnapThresholdInPixels = 20;

        void Window_MouseLeftButtonDown ( object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e )
        {
            this.LastLeftClickPosition = e.GetPosition ( this );
            Mouse.Capture ( this );
        }

        void Window_MouseLeftButtonUp ( object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e )
        {
            Mouse.Capture ( null );
        }

        void Window_MouseMove ( object sender, MouseEventArgs e )
        {
            if ( e.LeftButton == MouseButtonState.Pressed )
            {
                var currentPosition = e.GetPosition ( this );

                var deltaX = currentPosition.X - this.LastLeftClickPosition.X;
                var deltaY = currentPosition.Y - this.LastLeftClickPosition.Y;

                Left += deltaX;
                Top += deltaY;

                this.SnapWindow ( );
            }
        }

        void SnapWindow ( )
        {
            var screens = System.Windows.Forms.Screen.AllScreens;

            foreach ( var screen in screens )
            {
                var workingArea = screen.WorkingArea;

                if ( Math.Abs ( this.Left - workingArea.Left ) < this.SnapThresholdInPixels )
                    this.Left = workingArea.Left;

                if ( Math.Abs ( this.Top - workingArea.Top ) < this.SnapThresholdInPixels )
                    this.Top = workingArea.Top;

                if ( Math.Abs ( this.Left + this.ActualWidth - workingArea.Right ) < this.SnapThresholdInPixels )
                    this.Left = workingArea.Right - ActualWidth;

                if ( Math.Abs ( this.Top + this.ActualHeight - workingArea.Bottom ) < this.SnapThresholdInPixels )
                    this.Top = workingArea.Bottom - ActualHeight;

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I red and tested your code but still I am sorry to say but don't understand what you intend to achieve by it.

Answer (score 1):

From your posted code it is not clear why the behavior is not as expected. We can only assume. For example a swapped screen alignment.

You can try the following code to see if it fixes the issue. The example explicitly detects the current screen the `Window` is dragged in. It also compensates the the case that primary and secondary screen order is swapped (which would result in negative screen locations to indicate the swapped order).

You should also consider to override the input event handlers inherited from `UIElement` instead of attaching custom event handlers to the event:

```cs
protected override void OnMouseLeftButtonDown(MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
  this.LastLeftClickPosition = e.GetPosition(this);
  _ = Mouse.Capture(this);
}

protected override void OnMouseLeftButtonUp(MouseButtonEventArgs e) 
  => Mouse.Capture(null);

protected override void OnMouseMove(MouseEventArgs e)
{
  if (e.LeftButton == MouseButtonState.Pressed)
  {
    Point currentPosition = e.GetPosition(this);

    double deltaX = currentPosition.X - this.LastLeftClickPosition.X;
    double deltaY = currentPosition.Y - this.LastLeftClickPosition.Y;

    this.Left += deltaX;
    this.Top += deltaY;

    SnapWindow();
  }
}

void SnapWindow()
{
  var windowAnchor = new System.Drawing.Point((int)this.Left, (int)this.Top);
  var windowBounds = new System.Drawing.Rectangle(windowAnchor, new System.Drawing.Size((int)this.RenderSize.Width, (int)this.RenderSize.Height));

  System.Drawing.Rectangle screenBounds = GetCurrentScreenNormalized(windowBounds);

  // Left bounds check
  if (Math.Abs(windowBounds.Left - screenBounds.Left) < this.SnapThresholdInPixels)
  {
    this.Left = Math.Abs(screenBounds.Left);
  }

  // Right bounds check
  if (Math.Abs(windowBounds.Right - screenBounds.Right) < this.SnapThresholdInPixels)
  {
    this.Left = Math.Abs(screenBounds.Right - windowBounds.Width);
  }

  // Top bounds check
  if (Math.Abs(windowBounds.Top - screenBounds.Top) < this.SnapThresholdInPixels)
  {
    this.Top = Math.Abs(screenBounds.Top);
  }

  // Bottom bounds check
  if (Math.Abs(windowBounds.Bottom - screenBounds.Bottom) < this.SnapThresholdInPixels)
  {
    this.Top = Math.Abs(screenBounds.Bottom - windowBounds.Height);
  }
}

private System.Drawing.Rectangle GetCurrentScreenNormalized(System.Drawing.Rectangle windowBounds)
{
  System.Windows.Forms.Screen currentScreen = System.Windows.Forms.Screen.AllScreens
    .First(screen => screen.WorkingArea.IntersectsWith(windowBounds));

  // Normalize screen coordinates:
  // Use absolute coordinates to compensate the case that the secondary screen is left from the primary screen.
  // This would result in negative (inverted) coordinates for the secondary screen.
  // For example top-left becomes S1(-1920;0) and not S1(1920;0) as one would expect.
  // But positioning an object at this negative coordinates results in effectigvely placing the object outside the screen bounds.
  // The negative-sign is inly symbolic to indicate the screen order.
  var normalizedScreenLocation = new System.Drawing.Point(Math.Abs(currentScreen.WorkingArea.Left), Math.Abs(currentScreen.WorkingArea.Top));
  var normalizedScreenBounds = new System.Drawing.Rectangle(normalizedScreenLocation, currentScreen.WorkingArea.Size);
  return normalizedScreenBounds;
}
```